# In Dark Souls, can player from different platforms interact with each other?

Tags: dark-souls

My friends own the PS3 version of the game, while I am playing on the Xbox 360. Will we be able to join each others' games?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, Sony & Microsoft don't want to share. This isn't a technical issue (examples: [*Shadowrun*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadowrun_(2007_video_game)) for Xbox 360 can play with the Windows version, [*Portal 2*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_2#PlayStation_3) supports the PlayStation 3, Mac OS X, Linux and Windows versions playing together), but is a very deliberate business decision on their parts to try and carve out as much of the userbase for their own exclusive use. Even in cases where companies run their own private servers outside of XBL and PSN, they don't let the users from one sandbox play with the users from another (even though essentially it is the same clients talking to the same server using the same protocol).

#### TL;DR

Microsoft and Sony are kings of their respective sandboxes and won't let anyone play a game with anyone in another sandbox.

Comment: Unfortunately this is sad and true..

Comment: I would like to point out that there are some technical issues to this as well. Making two different builds of a game play together is often a whole lot trouble, and a lot of developers won't go through with the trouble, even if they have the blessing from Sony and Microsoft.

Comment: @mordi2k It's not much of a technical issue. I've taken TCP programming and the TCP/IP stack doesn't care about the hardware or OS that either end of a connection is running. TCP takes care of things like endianness. As long as both applications can agree on all aspects of the protocol (simple in this case, as the developer can re-use all the code) there should be no problem in that regard. The only place where the two builds really differ has to do with the system calls and optimizations. Mac OS X, Linux & Windows games talk to each other all the time because of TCP's platform neutrality.

Comment: In addition, there's a big difference between MS and Sony regarding PSN and XBL. MS own XBL from end-to-end and developers can't bring their own servers into play; Sony allows developers to provide their own servers (ref: Portal 2 cross-play with Steam).

Comment: @MelBoyce I'm fairly sure that EA operates their own servers for the various sports games they put out, and Square Enix operates the _FFXI_ servers on their own.

Comment: @CyberSkull This is not as simple as you would believe. Technically TCP does handle a lot of things, BUT its faster brother is UDP, which is sometimes used in networked game programming.  There are issues that must be overcome when using UDP.  I'm not sure if Dark Souls relies on UDP vs TCP, but it is possible that UDP would bring extra complications to this issue.  Not a definitive resource but for some additional information: http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/udp-vs-tcp/

Comment: @Tux When talking about TCP I meant the whole TCP/IP stack, including UDP, SCTP, et al, are **platform neutral** and not the main issue here (although _Dark Souls_ is probably running a hybrid of TCP/UDP, depending on the functionality). Any issues regarding the implementation of TCP/IP on the respective consoles or computer platforms here are trivial when compared to the huge vested interest that Microsoft, Sony & Nintendo have made clear in **not** letting their user bases interact with one another.

Comment: @CyberSkull: The primary concern would be mismatches in the application protocol, above the socket level. That is, if the Xbox 360 build is a patch ahead of the PS3 build or vice versa, it is a pain to maintain a server that can talk to both. It is impossible to guarantee a patch is deployed at the same time on both services. (Which is not to say that Sony and Microsoft don't love their walled gardens as well.)

Comment: @JoeWreschnig That's easily handled by having the client declare their version when they connect to the server. The connection can then be passed to a server with the appropriate version of the protocol. Besides, XBL & PSN both enforce using the latest version of the client or forcing the client to remain offline.