# Why are there PC players playing in PS3 matches? 

Tags: battlefield-3

I don't know if this is a bug or not but I can prove what I'm saying. In some PS3 match summaries on **Battlelog** there are also stats from PC players.

See here for an example match

http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/battlereport/show/35341990/4/352764909/

Click the player name **LOWREDCOBAIN** on top and on that profile it mentioned as a PC player and the stats are all gone. This is not only for this particular match, there are several other matches emphasizes the same conclusion. I read this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32847/does-battlefield-3-support-cross-platform-multiplayer), but these match summaries gave me the doubt.

Other match summery example:

- http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/battlereport/show/35515982/4/352764909/
- http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/battlereport/show/35548079/4/352764909/
- http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/battlereport/show/35550440/4/352764909/

Comment: What is the question being asked here?

Comment: @Bora The question is in the title - its not usually possible for PS3 and PC players to play in the same match.

Answer (score 3):

You must have hit some Battlelog bug.

[According to BF3Stats that player LOWREDCOBAIN is PS3 player](http://bf3stats.com/stats_ps3/LOWREDCOBAIN).