# Summoning Across Platforms

Tags: dark-souls-2

I have searched the web, I cannot find an explicit answer to this anywhere. :(

**Can friends play co-operatively (i.e. summon each other) between platforms?**

I believe the answer is no because in may case, I am on PC my friend is on XBOX and we have different death clock values.

We would like to be sure it is not the internet, and it is by design we can't summon one another.

Thanks

Comment: They do not have this feature unfortunately. You can only access the respective server with the platform associated with it. Maybe someday every game will have cross-platform co-op, but not now :I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dark Souls 2 does not offer a cross platform multiplayer experience.

In today's gaming environment, cross platform multiplayer experience is possible, but rare because of [business decisions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/31787/30210).

Answer (score 1):

As slow_excellence mentioned in the comments, very few games or platforms have this capability.

I have also explicitly tried this with Dark Souls 2 on Xbox Live and Games for Windows Live, to no avail.

Comment: some games do offer cross-platform multiplayer. Portal 2 is one example.